# Is it possible to trigger to close an issue opened in crashlytics by a web post?

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

With crashlytics it is possible to report any issue as defined [here](https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/custom-web-hooks.html?web%20hooks#custom-web-hooks)

Well, is it possible to close a crashlytics issue by calling a URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Not currently! I know several folks would like us to add this in though.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to hearing from you about implementing this feature.